Change aggregation type of column in databricks dashboard
The databricks dashboard aggregates (sum) any numerical column by default based on the dimensions. Is there a way I can change the default sum aggregate to other aggregation types (min, max, median, etc.). Below is a snippet of the options seen for the column.

Appreciate any help here.
